# When is it useful to expand a function in a fourier series?

Tags: taylor-expansion, fourier-series

Taylor expansion is very useful when we approximate a complicated function near a point. Often we only have to know the first (or sometimes also second) derivative.

But in the case of expanding in a Fourier series, if the function is simple (like a polinomial) it gets more complicated.

If it is a complicated function, the integrals to calculate the coeficients may be very complicated (if  analytic integrals exists).

It seems that it is the opposite of Taylor expansion: instead of simplifying, it complicates.

When is it useful to substitute an analytical function by its Fourier expansion?

Comment: Simple and complicated are relative terms, and simplicity isn't the only consideration, so is accuracy. Taylor expansion that requires 100 terms to get desired accuracy is not very useful either, if Fourier series can achieve the same accuracy with 2 terms it will be more useful. And Fourier series can be accurate not just near a point but uniformly on an interval, and works for non-analytic functions as well. It can be simpler for approximately solving differential equations too, just as Taylor expansion, but for different types of equations, etc.

Comment: Also it can be used to find lots of different (usually very hard) infinite sums! The basal problem, for example, and the generalised version of it (with even powers) can be solved this way

Comment: Solving a non-homogeneous linear differential equation $L(y) = f$ might be particularly easy if the function $f$ is a Fourier basis function. Then if a function $F$ can be written as a sum of Fourier basis functions, we can solve $L(u) = F$ using superposition.

Comment: Fourier's original motivation was to understand the heat equation. This is explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Solving_the_heat_equation_using_Fourier_series